# Sort a Matrix by row preserving the columns

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to sort (ascending) a matrix by row preserving its columns.
For example, I have this matrix:

```
my_scores = [
        ['1', 0.03, 0.4, 0.6, 0.01, 0.1],
        ['2', 0.02, 0.5, 0.7, 0.01, 0.1],
        ['3', 0.01, 0.5, 0.7, 0.02, 0.3],
        ['4', 0.01, 0.5, 0.7, 0.03, 0.4],
        ['5', 0.03, 0.1, 0.2, 0.03, 0.4],
       ]
```

The column 1 (index 0) is not to sort it's just an informative column indicating the name of the element.
I have this vector [1,2,3,4,5] that says that i should first sort by my column 2 (of index 1) then by column 3, and so on...

So my matrix sort function would output:

```
[
['1', 0.03, 0.4, 0.6, 0.01, 0.1],
['5', 0.03, 0.1, 0.2, 0.03, 0.4],
['2', 0.02, 0.5, 0.7, 0.01, 0.1],
['4', 0.01, 0.5, 0.7, 0.03, 0.4],
['3', 0.01, 0.5, 0.7, 0.02, 0.3]]
```

For example if all the values of column 2 were different I just needed to sort by column 2 but since it has the same value in 1 & 5 elements and in 4 & 3 elements I had to sort them by column 3, then by column 4, then by column 4 and finally by column 5 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alter the sorting key by passing in `key` argument to `.sort()` function:

```
my_scores.sort(key=lambda row: row[1:], reverse=True)
```

The `lambda` key given returns the row minus the initial column, effectively ignoring it when sorting. We also ask for a *reverse* sort, so larger values first.

This results in:

```
>>> my_scores = [
...         ['1', 0.03, 0.4, 0.6, 0.01, 0.1],
...         ['2', 0.02, 0.5, 0.7, 0.01, 0.1],
...         ['3', 0.01, 0.5, 0.7, 0.02, 0.3],
...         ['4', 0.01, 0.5, 0.7, 0.03, 0.4],
...         ['5', 0.03, 0.1, 0.2, 0.03, 0.4],
...        ]
>>> my_scores.sort(key=lambda row: row[1:], reverse=True)
>>> import pprint 
>>> pprint.pprint(my_scores)
[['1', 0.03, 0.4, 0.6, 0.01, 0.1],
 ['5', 0.03, 0.1, 0.2, 0.03, 0.4],
 ['2', 0.02, 0.5, 0.7, 0.01, 0.1],
 ['4', 0.01, 0.5, 0.7, 0.03, 0.4],
 ['3', 0.01, 0.5, 0.7, 0.02, 0.3]]
```

Comment: Hi thank you :) could u explain me just the meaning of the lambda expression that you used: key=lambda row: row[1:]

Comment: @user2209128: it creates an anonymous function, it is called for each row in the matrix, and returns a copy of the row minus the first element. `row[1:]` is a slice, asking for a copy starting at the second element through to the end.